# Synchronizing Calls in Node.js to parse Request and send response after processing the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning Node.js but I am having trouble understating the part of synchronization of method call executions. This is what I am trying to achieve

My request data contains a file which I need to upload and on successful upload of the file I should send a response back to the client saying that upload is completed. Until then I want the client to wait for response.
Now what happens is the response is sent immediately without waiting for the upload to complete and fetch the path hence empty path gets sent to the client.

**file1.js**

```
{

    bodyparse : a file from data request object
    uploadedopath = file2.Uploadfile();
    
    console.log(uploadedpath );
    response.status (
    Uploaded successfuly with + uploadedpath ;

}
```

**file2.js**

```
{

    UploadFile() {
    
        uploadedpath = file3.UploadToStorageBlob();
    return uploadedpath;

}
```

**file3.js**

```
{

    UploadToStorageBlob()
    {
    //connect to blob storage
    uploadedpath = azurestorage.uplaodtoBloab(filepath);
    
    return uploadedpath;
    }
    }

}
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: Well everything by default in JS is synchronous. I'd look into Promises or async-await.

Comment: How does Promises work when the methods are spread across files in three different methods.